# How to conditionally lazy load dynamic imports in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I would like to trigger a dynamic import of a react component only after an image is loaded to prioritise first paint. The problem is, it's a context provider component and having some trouble as a result.

So I have a dynamic import here in the file `auth.js`:

```
   const AuthContextPreloader = hasWindow
   ? lazy(() => import("./AuthContextPreloader"))
   : null;
```

And I have an image here in a separate component:

```
   <img
      ref={() => hasWindow && imageLoaded()}
      className={styles.optionsImageImg}
      alt={"nav"}
      src={didLoad && thumb.jpg}
      type="image/jpeg"
    />
```

And once loaded I a send state up the component tree to hand down to `AuthContextPreloader`

```
    const imageLoaded = () => {
      setheroLoaded(true);
     };
```

Some pseudo-code to try and achieve this in `auth.js`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    props.heroLoaded && **trigger the lazyload**;
  }, [props.heroLoaded]);
```

But totally unsure how to implement that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be concerned about *when* your component will be loaded. Your concern should be *when* to render it. Something like that:

```js
const AuthContextPreloader = hasWindow
  ? lazy(() => import("./AuthContextPreloader"))
  : null;

function ComponentWhereWouldBeRenderedAuthContextPreloader(props) {
  return props.heroLoaded ? <Suspense><AuthContextPreloader /> </Suspense> : null;
}
```

This way you will not consider yourself with internals, but will render your current application state.

### Edit

From the comments it is clear that your concern not the component itslef, but it's large dependency.

In this case you can do something like this:

```js
function ComponentWhereWouldBeRenderedAuthContextPreloader(props) {
  return props.heroLoaded ? <AuthContextPreloader /> : null;
}

function AuthContextPreloader(props) {
  let [dependencyState, setDependencyState] = useState("not_loaded");
  useEffect(function () {
    import("large-dependency")
      .then(function (module) {
        // return either default, or named exports that you need, or skip this step
        return module.default;
      })
      .then(function (dep) {
        // do something with dependency and then change state
        setDependencyState("loaded");
      });
  }, []);
  if (depenencyState === "not_loaded") return null;
  return ...;
}
```

Comment: The reason I am concerned with when is because that component imports firebase (70kb+), that's why I am deferring the import.

Comment: But it will not be rendered until `heroRendered`

Comment: Also, if you concerned about firebase, you can load and initialize it dynamically in `useEffect`, so it would be imported only after component will render

Comment: @user1088793 do you need to import the entire firebase default module? Or have you considered using more selective imports?

Comment: @ezhikov this lazy loads the module by default regardless of the condition I believe..

Comment: @Benjamin, that is the lib sizes of auth and app combined which are imported selectively.