# lazy loaded modules share same dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, chart.js, lazy-loading

I am using webpack and react and charts from different plugins (chartjs. etc).
I want to dynamically import the indivudal charts (bar, polar, line, etc..) with `React.lazy()` and display about ~20 of them (sometimes repeatedly with different data) in one dashboard.

I thought about dynamic import because i expect a growing number of chart components and want to keep those out of the main bundle. Also i feel i cannot put them into one bundle and load them once since some of them use different dependencies and not all of them are shown on a dashboard.

So my main question is, is there somehow a way to bundle the dependency (i.e. chartjs) of some of the chart components and load this dependency only once if necessary? Or is there a smarter way for this performance problem?

Comment: You can use webpack magic comments and specify a webpack chunk name. Does this help?  https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments

Comment: I’ve done a similar thing where I dynamically load a particular chart type. Each chart type specifies a particular chunk name (webpack magic comment)

Comment: @NathanHall Thank you !  in your link i found the following line:

`Dynamically load modules. Calls to import() are treated as split points, meaning the requested module and its children are split out into a separate chunk.`

Does that mean that each chart has a separate chunk but the common dependency (i.e. chartjs) is in a separate chunk and is reshared among the charts? If yes that would solve my problem

Comment: It will only load the chart dependency if needed and will not duplicate it across other dynamic imports. Also, you can define webpack chunk name for each dynamic import

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally lazy load dynamic imports in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66484409/how-to-conditionally-lazy-load-dynamic-imports-in-react)

Comment: @Mr.Hedgehog yes it does, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically load modules. Calls to import() are treated as split points, meaning the requested module and its children are split out into a separate chunk.

By adding comments to the import, we can do things such as name our chunk or select different modes.

Example

```
import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "my-chunk-name" */
  /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
  'module'
);
```